# The power set under intersection and addition as a ring

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

If $D$ is a set and $P(D)$ its power set, and $A+B=(A-B) \cup (B-A)$, $AB=A \cap B$ how come $P(D)$ is not a suitable identity?

Also, I would appreciate it if someone could elaborate on why if $A \cap A^{-1}=D$ that $A=A^{-1}=D$? Intuitively this makes sense, but is there an axiom or such that I can use to better explain this property?

I understand that $D$ itself is an identity, and as such is unique. But shouldn't $P(D)$ work as well? Can someone provide a counter example?

Comment: $P(D)\notin P(D)$.

Comment: @egreg I don't know what to say that is so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (multiplicative) identity must be an element of $P(D)$ and $P(D)$ doesn't qualify: $P(D)\notin P(D)$, in general. And $D=P(D)$ is impossible, by the way. So, even if $P(D)\in P(D)$, it wouldn't be a multiplicative identity, because you already know that $D$ is.

The only element having a multiplicative inverse is $D$. Suppose $AB=A\cap B=D$. Then $D\subseteq A$, so $A=D$.

Comment: @phatty Don't worry, it happens. `;-)` The important thing is straightening up the ideas.